# expression must have a const value

Tags: c++

I'm falling into a trouble and cannot fix it, can someone help me and if you can explain me the error please

```
template<unsigned long x>
struct dis
{
    dis() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};
unsigned int bina(unsigned long x)
{
    return x == 0 ? 0 : x % 10 + 2 * bina(x / 10);
}
int main()
{
    unsigned long b;
    std::cout << "Give a binary number:";
    std::cin >> b;
    dis<bina(b)>out; //here's the error
    return 0;
}
```

the error is: expr must have a const value

Comment: `constexpr` applied to function allows it to work in both compile-time and run-time evaluation, it could stay there alright.

Comment: `constexpr` here means it will be evaluated at compile time if the arguments happen to be known at compile time. `consteval` keyword will guarantee compile-time evaluation at some point in the future but it isn't supported by many compilers (if any) yet.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen a result based on runtime input can never serve as template argument though

Comment: @M.M Yes, that's explained in the answer to the question. I was referring to (now deleted) comment that `constexpr` was wrong because the function is called with arguments known at run-time only.

Comment: @M.M you mean if I use a runtime input, I have not to use template?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: why are you using template ?

Comment: if you want to use template create a template function instead a template struct.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is not a constant expression, so `bina(b)` neither.

You might change `dis` to accept runtime value:

```
struct dis
{
    dis(unsigned long x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

constexpr unsigned int bina(unsigned long x)
{
    return x == 0 ? 0 : x % 10 + 2 * bina(x / 10);
}
int main()
{
    unsigned long b;
    std::cout << "Give a binary number:";
    std::cin >> b;
    dis /*out*/(bina(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how did you know that struct dis was determined at compile time?

Comment: (non type) template parameters should be known at compile time.

Comment: You cannot, indeed. Runtime values cannot be used as template parameter.

Comment: what's the diff between ```dis(unsigned long x)``` and ```dis()```

Comment: constructor with or without parameter.